# attached Listener should not listen on label next to checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I attached an EventListener on a Checkbox. Right next to the checkbox is a symbol (Euro-Symbol). The Euro-Symbol should not be clickable, however, with my code, the checkbox and the label next to it are clickable. Do you know, what I did wrong here?

I've created the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="ui-myProject-radio ui-myProject-fieldset clearfix">
  <input type="radio" name="prefrage1_unit" value="1" id="prefrage1_unit_id_1" data-property-name="PRE_FRAGE1_EINHEIT"/>
  <label class="prefrage1_bottom_right_in_label" for="prefrage1_unit_id_1">
    {{Str.euro_sign}}
  </label>
</div>
```

With the following JavaScript snippet:

```
var unit = new RadioButton({
  selectors: ['#prefrage1_unit_id_0', '#prefrage1_unit_id_1'],
  sessionStorageKey: SessionKey.forms.PRE_FRAGE1.PRE_FRAGE1_EINHEIT.key,
  initialValue: 0
  }).create();

page.fields.unit = unit;

page.fields.unit.on('click', function () {
  page.validateForm();
});
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: try the change event instead of click event

Comment: This sounds like the elements are overlapping to me, check them out with the inspect element tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your are using the `for` attribute with `label`, which triggers event for the target element, here its the checkbox.

Try removing the `for` attribute from the label.

Comment: Regarding to W3C, The <label> element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the <label> element, it toggles the control. So I should somehow try to name the input field without the label tag.